# Closest path between turbines to existing paths

Tags: arcgis-pro, cost-path, path

I need to create the access road from the existing path to the turbines installed. We already have a layer with the existing path. I want to find the closest path through this existing path. Also I need to consider the slope of the area.

The path line layer I transform into points and then I calculate the closest point to the turbine by means of a spatial join.

I did:

1. Calculate slope
2. Reclassify slope: 0-12 % I give 1 more than 12 % 5.
3. Reclassify path layer: I transform into raster and then I gave 1 to the raster and 5 no data as you need to go through those paths.
4. Apply weighted overlay: give 50 % to each one.
5. Cost distance: input raster or feature source date: Turbines as origin date and inout cost raster: the output layer resulted by the weight overlay.
6. Cost blank link: the same.
7. Cost path: origin and destination (the path).

The result is not what I expected. Is there another way to calculate it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I prefer if you can propose the way that how you would do it because maybe my idea is no the correct

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! The order of things seem quite correct. However I think you can skip reclassification of path layer to make it simpler? These steps can then be followed:

1. Calculate slope
2. Reclassify slope: 0-12 % gets cost of 1 | 12+ % gets cost of 5.
3. Cost distance: feature source data = turbines | input cost raster = reclassified slope.
4. Cost back link: feature source data = turbines | input cost raster = reclassified slope.
5. Cost path: feature destination data = existing network/roads/paths | cost distance raster = cost distance from step 3 | cost backlink raster = cost back link from step 4 | path type = each cell.

Extra sources with background info (especially the youtube video seems helpful):

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cost-path.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/creating-the-least-cost-path.htm
https://youtu.be/0fhwaojCkAU?t=2235

Comment: You must distinguish between the longitudinal slope of the road and the cross section slope of the terrain. The software will calculate the cross section slope of the terrain and not the road. Maybe I didn't understand the question?